# Repeating code twice IOS-Dropbox

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox

This might seem a stupid question, but I don't know how to fix it.
I am uploading 2 files to dropbox in this way:

```
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename1 toPath:destDir
        withParentRev:nil fromPath:tmpPngName];

[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename2 toPath:destDir
        withParentRev:nil fromPath:tmpPngName];
```

The problem is that when there is an error this method is called 2 times because of the 2 failed uploads:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {

NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error);

    NSString *filename1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@newFile.json", NavBar.topItem.title];
    [[self restClient] loadRevisionsForFile:filename2 limit:2];

    NSString *filename2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@Map.json", NavBar.topItem.title];
    [[self restClient] loadRevisionsForFile:filenameMap limit:2];

}
```

And id' like it to call it only once, because in this method I execute the code to solve the issue for both files! How can I do that?

Comment: Try uploading one and waiting for a result, and then upload the other.

Comment: I would not group them together in that way. Just because one fails doesn't mean you want the other to restart. I would suggest refactoring and finding a better way to handle for errors on a per file basis. This approach is super fragile.

Comment: ok, then please give my an idea on how to do it, because I have no idea! I fixed the problem but by using an Integer which I use as counter.